# Exclude certain characters when validating text from two documents

Tags: c#

Using C#, I am validating the text of two log files that should be exactly the same. The exception is that one log file appends `"= :::"` to the end of every line, which throws off the validation.

Is there a way to validate the two documents' content, but exclude that specific string from the validation?

Comment: You can have a look at [string.TrimEnd()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx)

Comment: I'm sure there is a way with `Regex`, although I am not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the second file in placed in `x`, you can do

```
x.Replace("= :::\n", "\n");
```

that will work for all lines except the last, so you can do for the last

```
x.remove(x.LastIndexOf("= :::\n"));
```